# Will more git features to coming to Files?

Tags: pantheon-files

I've noticed a change to the Files app in the most recent update to elementary OS; it now shows git file status (new, modified, staged, etc.):

[image]

Will more git integration features be coming to the Files app? For instance, having commands like `git add` in the right-click context menu would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, requests for other git features have already been filed at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues such as the ability to change branch.  I do not think `git add` has been requested there yet so please do so if you wish